# Why does a CHAR(1) in SQL take 1 byte while a char in java takes 2 bytes?

Tags: java, sql, char, character

I was reading into SQL/92 (I'm new to it) and it went through the different datatypes. One of them is CHAR which of course I know is fairly similar to the String in java, not the char in java. But let us assume it is CHAR(1). Just one character.

In SQL/92 it says each character is 8 bits. In java, however, one character is 16 bits. Additionally, a Character in general takes up 16 bits does it not?

Note this is not a duplicate because I am not asking the difference between a CHAR and VARCHAR or SQL char and a unicode ascii char.

So my question is: why is a char in Java 16 bits and a CHAR(1) in SQL/92 8 bits?

-Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL and C were developed when supporting extended ASCII seemed good enough. It certainly worked fine in Latin languages. esp in the USA.

Later, Unicode was more widely excepted as needed so it could be used in more countries, which needed wider characters. Java being newer started supporting Unicode from 0 to 65535.

Note: Since then, Unicode now needs more than 16 bits and Java support UTF-16 for even wider characters e.g. emojis.

In hindsight, `char` should have been an `unsigned int` and the `Character` class now support `int` for "codepoints"

Java 9+ now uses 8-bit per character in a String if it can to save space. ;)

Comment: So it is simply was SQL was less.. globalized. Less extensive? And does that mean SQL does not support as many characters as Java does?

Comment: @JustAFellowCoder In SQL you need to use `NCHAR` and `NVARCHAR` for wider characters. These types were added later.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Or you can set your database encoding to UTF-8 if your SQL implementation allows it.

Answer (score 4):

> Additionally, a Character in general takes up 16 bits does it not?

Historically, a character took up 7 (ASCII) or 8 (EBCDIC or “extended ASCII”) bits.

Unicode assigns each character an integer “code point” between 0 and 0x10FFFF, so in the most straightforward encoding, each character is 21 bits.

(Well, not exactly.  Thanks to combining characters and ligatures, the number of Unicode code points in a string may differ from the number of user-perceived characters.  But for simplicitly's sake, I'm assuming a one-to-one correspondence between “character” and “code point”.)

There are three commonly-used ways to encode Unicode characters into “code units”:

- UTF-32 is the most straightforward one: Each character is encoded as a single 32-bit code unit.  (This “wastes” 11 bits, but is easy to implement on a 32- or 64-bit computer.)
- UTF-16 uses one 16-bit code unit for “Basic Multilingual Plane” characters, and a two-unit “surrogate pair” for other characters (including most emoji).
- UTF-8 uses between 1 and 4 bytes for each character.  It is “optimized” for the characters inherited from 7-bit US-ASCII, which take only one byte each.

All three encoding forms can represent all Unicode characters, but differ in memory usage and ease of processing.

> So my question is: why is a char in Java 16 bits and a CHAR(1) in SQL/92 8 bits?

Historical reasons.  SQL was developed in the 1970s when internationalized software wasn't much of a thing, and simple 8-bit character encodings were good enough for English, or other languages with alphabetic writing systems.  (For East Asians, the situation was more complicated.)

Java was developed in the early 1990s, not long after Unicode was introduced.  At the time, Unicode assumed that 16 bits would be good enough for everyone, so 16-bit characters were the obvious choice for new platforms.  (Windows NT was developed around the same time, and also uses UTF-16 strings.)

Languages already in wide use were retrofitted with additional character types to represent these new “wide” characters: C and C++ got `wchar_t`, and SQL got `NCHAR` and `NVARCHAR`.